# What does the following sed command do: sed -i "s/,$//' <filename>

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I'm new to `sed`.

Can someone explain what `sed -i "s/,$//'` means?

Comment: It means you have an incomplete command because the quotes don't match. You've opened both double and single quotes and closed neither.

Comment: I'd recommend the [sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't seems correct, the good writting could be:

```
sed -i 's/,$//' "filename"
```

I replaced the opening double quote (`"`) by a simple (`'`)

Let's explain:

- `-i` in place: the file given in argument will be changed.
- `s` substitute: `s/pattern/string/` it a replacement regex, matched `pattern` will be replaced with `string`
- the pattern: `,$`: will match quote (`,`) followed by a line feed (`\n`)
- the replacement string (empty):  : the pattern will be simply deleted.

So you sed command will transform a file like

```
a,b,c,
e,f,g
h,i,j,,
```

into

```
a,b,c
e,f,g
h,i,j,
```